# Set external content type by javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, external-content-type

In the *NewForm*, I need to set an **external Content Type lookup field** by *javascript*.
How can I do it?

Comment: Nk SP: What all solutions you have tried so far?

Comment: I have the ID and the value of the field, I tried to set it as a normal field, but is not working. I think I miss a kind of validation